# highlight empty input fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form where the user inputs numbers. A function is called on click. I want to highlight and empty any invalid fields (those that are not numbers). So far it highlights and clears all inputs. I need just the ones that are not filled in, or that have input that is not a number.

```js
   function validatefilledIn() {
    "use strict";
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var score = document.getElementById('total');
    
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
     if(isNaN(parseInt(arr[i].value))) {
      
      alert("Please make sure all the fields are filled in.");
      $('input').val('').css( "border-color", "red" );
      $('#form1').find('#total').val('');
      return false;
     }
     
    }
   }
```

```html
          <form name="myForm" id="form1">
              <fieldset>
                   <input  type="text" name="qty"  id="qty1" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>   
                   <input  type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                   <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty3" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                   <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                   <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty5" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                   <input type="text" name="qty"  id="qty6" oninput="findTotal()"class="hvr-pop" required/>    
             </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: how do you plan to distinguish between fields with the same name on server?

Comment: What do you suggest? I thought it could cycle through the names in the function.

Comment: Do I need to change my question? Not sure what to do.

Comment: console.log is your friend. Try outputting `arr[i].value` to the console and that might shed some light. Also, @Lashane's advice is important. The name can be an array but you wouldn't be able to tell which is which on the server. I'd set the name to be the same as the id in your case. Given that the names won't all be the same, you'll need to iterate over your "hvr-pop" class instead. `$('.hvr-pop').each(function () { // check if valid values and update style here});`

Comment: Thank you, Steve I will change the names and iterate over the hvr-pop. What is the code for selecting only the fields ate are empty? This code selects them all: $('input').val('').css( "border-color", "red" ); I just want to modify the empty inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `if(isNaN(arr[i].value) || arr[i].value == "")` it does work!

```
function validatefilledIn() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        if(isNaN(arr[i].value) || arr[i].value == "") {
            $(arr[i]).val('').css( "border-color", "red" );
        }
    }
}
```

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function findTotal() {
            }
            function validatefilledIn() {
                var arr = $("[name='qty']");
                $.each(arr, function(i, o) {
                    if(isNaN($(o).val()) || $(o).val() == "") {
                        $(o).val('').css( "border-color", "red" );
                    } else {
                        $(o).css( "border-color", "green" );
                    }
                });
            } 
        </script>
        <form name="myForm" id="form1">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>   
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty2" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty3" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty5" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty6" oninput="findTotal()" class="hvr-pop" required/>    
            </fieldset>
            <button onClick="validatefilledIn()">Check</button>
        </form>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Petres, but it still selects all the inputs. I just want to add a red border on the empty ones.

Comment: ```$('input')``` will select all inputs, so there you have also to select only the one which has bad data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I don't know how to do, select the ones with bad input. I tried 
            $(arr[i]).val('').css( "border-color", "red" ); but it returns the only first input box, not the empty ones. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you still the ```return false``` in there? Then it will stop after the first one!

Comment: I tried it without return false, it created an endless loop. Also tried return true. Still just returns the first one. Is there a way to stop it after iterating 6 times? I have 6 input boxes

Comment: When do you call ```validatefilledIn()```?

Comment: when  button is pressed outside of the form

Comment: Not sure what that means. When I click the button, only the first field is selected. does that answer the question?

Comment: I added an html example, that works in that way you wished